# Objective-C NSArray troubles

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Ok I am trying to deal a deck of cards at certain positions, but I am stuck at a spot. I am only dealing one less than the max. I am trying to deal to every spot in the index of the nsarray.

```
- (CGPoint)animateDealingToPlayer:(Player *)player withDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    self.frame = CGRectMake(-100.0f, -100.0f, CardWidth, CardHeight);
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

    NSArray *position = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:




                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)],
                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)],
                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)],
                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)],
                         [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10,   50)],


                         nil];


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        NSValue *value = [position objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));

        self.center = point;


    }

}
```

I am dealing the card at 10,50 and not dealing the card at previous positions such as 0,0. This is probably easy to solve, but I can't seem to remember how to fix this. Please help me. Also, note that I am still somewhat new to objective c so you may have to dumb this down if you solve this lol.

Comment: It's very unclear exactly what you are asking.  Are you seeing the 5 data points in the log?  You are re-assigning self.center each time.  Only the last one in the loop sticks.

Comment: Yes exactly! Is there a way that it does it individual each time instead of resigning. My cards are going  10,50 each time, but i want it  to go (0,0) 4 times then go (10,50).

Comment: It is like that the loop is executing so fast the you only see the last card.  Do you see the log output?

Comment: you're only animating 1 object... It goes through the first 4 positions for the single card, then goes to the last position, and thats the only one you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the cards position 5 times without doing any animation or giving the card object a chance to be redrawn in between changing it's position. iOS doesn't actually position the card until the run loop gets a chance to fire. There are a number of possible solutions, but you should probably look into adding an animation block inside your loop so that the movement is queued for the the display.